# What is Verilog's default value for unspecified higher bits in $readmemb?

Tags: verilog

If I have a Verilog memory which is 12 bits wide and I initialize it using `$readmemb` from a Verilog binary file whose entries are, say, 5 bits wide, what will the values of `[11:5]` be?

SSCCE below. I've run it with `iverilog` and it pads the upper bits with 0's, but I'd love to know if that assumption is portable or if this is unspecified behavior.

testbench.v:

```
module testbench();
  reg [11:0] memory [0:7];

  initial begin: main
    integer i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) memory[i] = 12'hxx;
    $readmemb("test_mem.bin", memory, 0, 7);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) $display("%h", memory[i]);
  end
endmodule
```

test_mem.bin:

```
11111
10000
10000
11111
11011
11010
10001
10001
```

Answer (score 0):

The [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) says in section *21.4 Loading memory array data from a file* that the numbers are read in the same as if they were in a SystemVerilog source description, except there is no width or base. Just assume that `'h` is in front of the number for `$readmemh` and `'b` is in front of the number for `$readmemb`. Using the rules in *5.7.1 Integer literal constants*, it says

> If the size of the unsigned number is smaller than the size specified
> for the literal constant, the unsigned number shall be padded to the
> left with zeros. If the leftmost bit in the unsigned number is an x or
> a z, then an x or a z shall be used to pad to the left, respectively.
> If the size of the unsigned number is larger than the size specified
> for the literal constant, the unsigned number shall be truncated from
> the left.

You can try this in many simulators and they all produce the same results. https://edaplayground.com/x/67_C

Comment: "the numbers are read in the same as if they were in a SystemVerilog source description".   None of the verilog compilers on EDAPlayground sign extend if I declare the reg / logic as `signed`.

Comment: The text I quoted above says literal padding is always with zeros.

Comment: I had assumed that integers in the file would be treated as signed if the memory they were being read into was signed. Paragraph 7 of 5.7.1 seems to clarify this "numbers shall be treated as ... unsigned integers if the base format only is used."

Comment: Because 21.4 says "The numbers [in the bin or hex file] shall have neither the length nor the base format specified", it seems to me that the Verilog spec doesn't make clear whether these numbers are treated as signed or unsigned integers. However, all of the implementers whose stuff is on EDAPlayground seem to have made the (reasonable) assumption that the numbers in the file should be treated as unsigned.

Comment: `$readmem` existed long before `signed` was added to Verilog, and probably no one went back to clarify this behavior. (15 years)

Comment: "$readmem existed long before signed was added to Verilog" @dave_59 It would be pretty cool if you dropped nugget of knowledge that in your answer :)